# What are the topic names for the JMS interface for OpenNMS

Tags: jms, opennms

I am trying to make a JMS connection from a Java program to OpenNMS. I am able to connect to OpenNMS over JMS but I do not know what topics I can subscribe to. Is there a list of topic names? Do they have associated JNDI names? Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for OpenNMS, but the good JNDI implementations support listing of entries. Such as this:

```
NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list = ctx.list("");
while (list.hasMore()) {
  System.out.println(list.next().getName());
}
```

And also you can check the User Guide for some of the event (topic) names:

https://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/latest/guide-user/guide-user.html